# Using sed or awk to extract text from xml file

Tags: xml, shell, awk, sed, xml-parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"??>
<resources>
<data id="V701">
    <string name="MSG_V701_ID">V701</string>
    <string name="MSG_V701_TITLE">abc</string>
    <string name="MSG_V701_BODY">This title is currently unable</string>
</data>
<data id="V702">
    <string name="MSG_V702_ID">V702</string>
    <string name="MSG_V702_TITLE">Play</string>
    <string name="MSG_V702_BODY">This title is currently unable to play</string>
```

Using this xml i want to find values of all tags related to particular id

for eg id="V701"
V701
abc
This title is currently unable

for id="V702"
V702
Play
This title is currently unable to play
i want to use this in bash script so please print output one per line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are generally better off using a tool that understands XML to parse an XML file, rather than trying to parse it using things like `sed` or `awk`. For example, the `xmllint` command has a `--xpath` option that you can use to extract information from an XML file:

```
$ ID=V702
$ result=$(xmllint --xpath "//data[@id='$ID']" data.xml)
$ echo "$result"
<data id="V702">
    <string name="MSG_V702_ID">V702</string>
    <string name="MSG_V702_TITLE">Play</string>
    <string name="MSG_V702_BODY">This title is currently unable to play</string>
</data>
```

Or even:

```
$ result=$(xmllint --xpath "//data[@id='$ID']//text()" data.xml)
$ echo "$result"


V702


Play


This title is currently unable to play
```

---

If you want individual strings, you can do something like this:

```
title=$(xmllint --xpath "//data[@id='$ID']/string[@name='MSG_${ID}_TITLE']/text()" data.xml)
body=$(xmllint --xpath "//data[@id='$ID']/string[@name='MSG_${ID}_BODY']/text()" data.xml)
```

Comment: how to make id="V702" as general way like id can be anything as i will pass variable instead of "V702"

Comment: You can just put your target ID in a variable and use that. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: as output is showing in one line how to show that output to another line means how to break that line

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking in that last comment.

Comment: V702 Play This title is currently unable to play. 
when i do echo to variable to show me output so  it show output in just one line how to show output line by line.

Comment: If you store the output of `xmllint` in a variable, you can quote the variable when `echo`-ing to preserve newlines. I've updated the answer to demonstrate this.

Comment: V702
Play
This title is currently unable to play.
how to pick these values using tere index 
means line by line 
actually i want to make a html page with different row
how to do that.

Comment: is there any way  by which we can convert this xml file to json using command line or shell script?